# Setting color in two different ways @*android:color/color1 vs @android:color/color1

Tags: android

I have seen this example:

```
@*android:color/secondary_text_light
```

What's that * asterisk doing there? What is the difference when using or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know in Android XML it is supposed to be a wildcard, replacing any number, but it seems an odd placement to me.

There is nothing about it in the documentation or guide, other than [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)

Perhaps it is a bug or mistake that doesn't cause compilation errors.